# How to Integrate Robot framework Tests results to Kibana

Tags: python, robotframework, kibana

I am new to Robot Framework. I have 5 test files which has 10 test cases each i.e 50 test cases automated. I would want to integrate all the test cases result (Pass/Fail) to kibana. Is there a way to integrate?

I have below Implementation so far

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  ../sample.robot
Resource  ../sample2.robot

Library  sample1.py
Library           OperatingSystem

Suite Setup  Run Keywords
...    Connect To DB1 And DB2

Suite Teardown  Run Keywords
...    Disconnect From DB1 And DB2

*** Variables ***

${var1}    null

*** Test Cases ***
TC1_sample
     ...
....
.....
....

TC2_sample
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is the observed  result from that attempt?